# Как на питоне вывести фото, если быть верней найти путь к нему(файлу)

Tags: python, telebot, path, photo

У меня нет определенного кода, верней есть но он большой нет смысла вставлять вот вставил кусочек который я нашел в инете но мне все равно выдает ошибку в стиле no such file or directory. Я понимаю что я где то близко и что то упускаю, наставьте на путь истинный новичка пожалуйста!(Ах да забыл сказать все я это делаю для бота в телеграмм с библиотекой pytelegrambotAPI. (import telebot)

```py
p = open('photo.png', 'rb')  
bot.send_photo(chat.id, p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по коду это телеграмм бот. Функция send_photo принимает не файл, а путь до него:

```
bot.send_photo(chat.id, 'photo.png')
```

Comment: Хорошо понял, но когда я вставляю туда путь у меня слеши подсвечиваются все равно оранжевым и выдает ошибку..

Comment: вставь перед строкой r

bot.send_photo(chat.id, r'photo.png')

Comment: либо ставь двойные слэши, это называется экранирование символов

Comment: все равно не дает, такая ошибка
 bot.send_photo(chat.id, r'photo.png')
NameError: name 'chat' is not defined

Comment: Ошибка потому что, chat это вложенный класс, он хранится в другом классе, который тебе присылает телеграмм

Comment: и что мне делать? может быть я фулл код кину?

Comment: покажи код, хендлера или листенера, или через что ты отслеживаешь входящие сообщения

Comment: ```python
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
```

Answer (score 0):

Все я наконец то вышел из положения!
Вот код

```py
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'your URL')
```